# Changing values in multiple columns using Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reset the document to default based on the value in Column E or 5. I would then like to change the value of the cell in both column 5 and 7.

When I run without the `Cells (x,7)` lines it works.

```
Sub Reset_Submitted_Document_HW_ALSTOM()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Dim answer As Integer
 
answer = MsgBox("Do you want to reset the Submittted Document for Sign Of Year? This is typically performed at year end to clear the tracker.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Reset Submitted Document Checkmark")

If answer = vbYes Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case (Cells(x, 5))

        Case "Reset Default Date"
            Cells(x, 5) = "Reset Default Date"
            Cells(x, 7).Formula = "=Today()"
 
        Case "Final Update"
            Cells(x, 5) = "Reset Default Date"
            Cells(x, 7).Formula = "=Today()"
 
        Case "Final Action Taken SPD"
            Cells(x, 5) = "Populate Previous SPD"
            Cells(x, 7) = ""
 
        Case "Populate Previous SPD"
            Cells(x, 5) = "Populate Previous SPD"
            Cells(x, 7) = ""
 
        Case Else
            Cells(x, 5).Formula = "="""""

        End Select

    Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    MsgBox "No Updates have been made to the tracker."

End If

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Update: The answered code runs but does not change the date, nor reset cells in column E that say "Final Update" to "Reset Default Date". I'm thinking it may have something to do with xlUp stopping part way down column E.

Screenshot of how the sheet is structured.
[image]

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: I recieve the "Run-time error '1004' "Application-defined or object-defined error. Then highlights the Cells (x,7).Formula = "=Today()" line

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that line.  Might be worth making your code a little more robust by explicitly qualifying all of your `Cells()` with a worksheet reference.

Comment: Ya I had worksheet references previously, but I wanted the work sheet to be dynamic. I may resort back to my original code that did not use case

Comment: You can still have it act on the activesheet, but `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet` and then use `ws` in the rest of your code.  You should never have `Cells()` or `Range()` by itself outside of a worksheet code module (where the default sheet is always the module's sheet and not ActiveSheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some Minor Corrections

If you don't use `Option Explicit` (not recommended), there is no error. When you use it, there is a compile error because `x` isn't `dim`med.

The lines that contain `.formula` should be changed, because e.g. the data will be changed to the date when you open the workbook again, but you need the date when the reset was done. Similarly you don't want the formula ="" in a column with only values.

If you want to do the same thing for two conditions in a `Select Case` statement, you separate them by a comma in the same case. The comma means `Or`.

If the code stops in the middle, `ScreenUpdating` will stay `False`. Do some `Error` handling.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Reset_Submitted_Document_HW_ALSTOM()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Dim answer As Long
    Dim x As Long

    answer = MsgBox("Do you want to reset the Submittted Document " _
      & "for Sign Of Year? This is typically performed at year end to clear " _
      & "the tracker.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, _
      "Reset Submitted Document Checkmark")

    If answer <> vbYes Then MsgBox _
      "No Updates have been made to the tracker.": GoTo ProgramExit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        On Error GoTo ProgramError

        For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            Select Case (Cells(x, 5))
                Case "Reset Default Date", "Final Update"
                    Cells(x, 5) = "Reset Default Date"
                    Cells(x, 7) = Date ' Cells(x, 7).Formula = "=Today()"
                Case "Final Action Taken SPD", "Populate Previous SPD"
                    Cells(x, 5) = "Populate Previous SPD"
                    Cells(x, 7) = ""
                Case Else
                    Cells(x, 5) = "" 'Cells(x, 5).Formula = "="""""
            End Select
        Next

SafeExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ProgramExit:
    ActiveSheet.Protect

Exit Sub

ProgramError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred."
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo SafeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Screenupdating always resets itself as soon as your code exits - it is not "sticky" like EnableEvents or Calculation

Comment: @Tim Willams: Had no idea. Should I still write the code like this? I last used it on Excel 2003 or even earlier. Can it be that it was 'sticky' there?

Comment: I don't remember how it was in 2003 (so long ago!) but I'd only use an error handler if turning off Events or Calculation: Screenupdating is "safe"

Comment: Appreciate the response, However I am still receiving a error. Ill upload a template document so you can see what I'm referring to.